# Objective-C Crash: Create object from Class

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface TestObject:NSObject
+(instancetype)Object;
@end

@implementation TestObject
+(instancetype)Object{
    TestObject *aObject = [[TestObject alloc]init];
    return aObject;
}
```

The above code work well！

But Xcode throw an “EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)” exception, 
when I changed the code to the following:

```
@interface TestObject:NSObject
+(id)Object;
@end

@implementation TestObject
+(id)Object{
    Class class =object_getClass(self);
    id aObject = [[class alloc]init];
   return aObject;
}
@end
```

Could anybody tell me why? Thx

[image]

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but in a static method `self` will refer to class , so you should be able to do `return [[self alloc] init]` not to rely on `TestObject` symbol.

Comment: @Kamil.S , Thank a lot. It works

Comment: @matt The bottom code snippet in OP question does crash indeed.

Comment: @Kamil.S So maybe your suggestion _does_ answer the question. If `self` is the class already, what does `Class class =object_getClass(self)` do? :)

Comment: @matt I update a Screenshot. Actually,
I am also confused about this. Because Class class =object_getClass(self) seems work well.

Comment: @matt Haha, thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` in a static `objective-c` method IS the **class**.

```
Class class = object_getClass(self);
```

returns the **metaclass**.

You can verify it with:

```
Class class = object_getClass(self);
Class class2 = objc_getMetaClass("TestObject");
Class class3 = self;
```

`class` & `class2` will be the same thing (metaclass) opposed to `class3` the actual class.